# Wordpress main static page url

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.6

Wordpress 4.6.

I set a static page as main page. And now url of main page is url of my static page.

What I need to do to make such url: www.mysite.com but not www.mysite.com/mypagename?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to change the URI of your home page? Normally when your page is the home page, the page will not have any permalink like `page_id=x`.

Comment: Conversely, I need a normal home page without permalink, but my Wordpress do it

Answer (score 0):

I understand. 
I have the plugin Polylang, that did  302 redirect to url of static page with prefix and permalink.

I change URL modifications settings - turn on checkbox "The front page url contains the language code instead of the page name or page id" and all is OK.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your `Wordpress admin pannel > Settings > Reading > Front page displays` and select your front page name from the drop down.

```
http://your.site/wp-admin/options-reading.php
```

Comment: I did as you said. But url is www.mysite.com/mypagename. not www.mysite.com/